# Weird HTTP Response Arduino

Tags: http, arduino, ethernet

So, I wrote a program than is supposes to connected to a server, and it returns the time. It works on my server, but when I tried to use it on another server, it responses oddly. Here is the response from my server:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Tue, 07 Jan 2014 00:06:20 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.22 (Debian)
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.4.4-14+deb7u5
Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=jlscamqbddtqibf9j7m0fu27p5; path=/
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Pragma: no-cache
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Length: 6
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html

4:06pm
```

which works great. Now here is the response from the other server (doesn't work):

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Tue, 07 Jan 2014 00:06:34 GMT
Server: Apache
Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=krlqmoqgpiqm9b9u27agup53c7; path=/
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Pragma: no-cache
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html

6
4:06pm
0
```

As you can see I'm getting some weird stuff before and after the expected response. The code on the server is exactly the same. And the code on the Arduino is the same except for the a couple strings.

Here is a pastebin of the code I am using: http://pastebin.com/TFF5h2Gw
Sorry there aren't a lot of comments and it's kinda jumbled together. I omitted a little bit of code that is used by other stuff that I haven't even gotten to test yet because I can't even get the time.

Comment: There's no `Content-Length:` either.  I seem to recall there are a few options where Content-Length need not explicitly be set, but I don't remember much about them.  You are probably going to have to look at the HTTP specs to understand when that might happen.

Comment: I think it is expecting a request that I'm not sending but I don't know what it would be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are seeing is a [chunk-encoded response](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chunked_transfer_encoding). That is okay as all HTTP/1.1 capable clients are supposed to understand this transport encoding. What is wierd is that the server is not explicitly marking the response as being chunk-encoded (This is usually done via the `Transer-Encoding: chunked` header).

A quick way to get rid of this is to issue a HTTP/1.0 request.

Comment: I don't recall why HTTP/1.0 doesn't work, but it doesn't. I will give it another try today though. Is there a way I can request it to not be encoded that way?

Comment: You can *try* to send an empty `TE` header. That would signal the server that no form of transport encoding were acceptable. No guarantee for success, though. I'd guess servers would only check if the client requested something via HTTP/1.1 and check no further.

Comment: Well, I don't remember why HTTP/1.0 didn't work before, but it worked this time so I'm not going to worry about it. I did however find that using `Accept-Encoding: gzip` also got rid of `Transfer-Encoding: chunked` but that didn't really help me with my Arduino project.